# Random 500 internal server error loading json data via ajax in Codeigniter project

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, d3.js, c3.js

I am loading json data that is displayed in graph via AJAX aas implemented by the c3js library (http://c3js.org).

The function that

```
site = 'http://example.co.ke/';
   var debits_ = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#account-debits',
    data: {
            x: 'time',
            xFormat: formart_,
            type:"area", 
            colors: {
                credit_type: '#1ABB9C'
            },
            url: site+"dashboard/credits_data/db/"+log_data,
            mimeType: 'json'
        });
```

I am making about 5 to 7 similar requests at the same time.

I however get random 500 Internal server error messages. (requests work and show data or give error randomly every time I make a new request)

No error

[image: no error]

Error

[image: error]

Error

[image: error]

Could the issue be caused by CodeIgniter session? What is a possible solution? It works well on localhost without any error but on a shared server it fails.

Comment: Can you show your php code? Or do you have access to error logs on the server? They are usually under `/var/log/apache2/error.log` on linux

Comment: There are no error logs. and the php output works and is json encoded.

Comment: click on the error link and you can see the response tab , in that there will be the exact error message .post it here . there are many causes of 500 error. so its hard to  fix by just seeing `500 error`.