# 500 error from query using JSON in CodeIgniter depending on query order

Tags: json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, c3.js

I'm working on a CodeIgniter (v3.1.9) project that displays graphs of data pulled from databases. I have 1 controller, 1 model, a main view, and each graph as subviews.

My **model** (currently only has 2 queries) that returns an array.

My **controller** is simple - an index function to pass the graph views to the main view and 2 functions for each graph. 1 that simply prints encoded json, and another that returns the graph view to the main view.

My **views** contain Javascript/jQuery that gets the JSON and creates/displays the graph (using c3js).

**The Problem:** One of the graphs displays fine and the other causes a 500 error. If I move the query causing the 500 above the other in my model.. both display fine and there is no error.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632735/random-500-internal-server-error-loading-json-data-via-ajax-in-codeigniter-proje) asked 2 years ago, but it remains unanswered.

What's causing this 500 error depending on the function order? How can I fix this?

**Controller:**

```
class ARDash extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model("ar_dash_model");
         $this->load->database();
         $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    public function index() {
        $data['content'] = array();
        array_push($data['content'], $this->displayReportsByClassification());
        array_push($data['content'], $this->displayReportsByOccupation());

        $this->load->view("Dash/AR/dash_view",$data);
    }

  function displayReportsByClassification() {
    return $this->load->view("Dash/AR/by_classification.php", null, true);
  }

  function jsonReportsByClassification() {
    $data = $this->ar_dash_model->dbGetReportsByClassification();
    print json_encode($data);
  }


  function jsonReportsByOccupation() {
    $data = $this->ar_dash_model->dbGetReportsByOccupation();
    print json_encode($data);
  }
  function displayReportsByOccupation() {
    $data = $this->load->view("Dash/AR/by_occupation.php", null, true);
    return $data;
  }
}
```

**Model:**

```
class ar_dash_model extends CI_Model {

  function dbGetReportsByClassification() {
    $results = array();
    $sql = '
    SELECT
        Event_Class_ID,
        EventClass_Name as name,
        count(Event_ID) as count
    FROM
        Reports.tblEvent as incident
        LEFT JOIN Reports.tblEventClass
          ON Event_Class_ID = EventClass_ID
    WHERE
        incident.Event_Deleted is null AND
        incident.Event_District_ID = '.$this->di.'
        AND
          Event_Occurred_Date_Time BETWEEN CAST("'.($this->dateRange["from"]).'" AS DATE) AND CAST("'.($this->dateRange["to"]).'" AS DATE)
    GROUP BY
        Event_Class_ID
    ORDER BY count DESC
        ';

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
      if($row->name != '') {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp['classification'] = $row->name;
        $tmp['count'] = $row->count;
        array_push($results, $tmp);
      }
    }
    return $results;
  }
}




/****************
* Moving this above the other function makes the 500 go away
*********/
function dbGetReportsByOccupation() {
  $results = array();
  $sql = '
  SELECT
    count(I.Event_ID) as count,
    O.Occupation_Name as occupation
  FROM
    Reports.tblEvent AS I INNER JOIN Reports.tblARPerson AS P ON I.Event_ARPerson_ID = P.ARPerson_ID INNER JOIN mainDb.tblResource as R ON I.Event_Resource_ID = R.Resource_ID INNER JOIN mainDb.tblOccupation as O ON R.Resource_Primary_Occupation_ID = O.Occupation_ID
  WHERE
    I.Event_District_ID = '.$this->di.'
  AND
    I.Event_Deleted is null
  AND
    I.Event_Occurred_Date_Time BETWEEN CAST("'.($this->dateRange["from"]).'" AS DATE) AND CAST("'.($this->dateRange["to"]).'" AS DATE)
  GROUP BY
    O.Occupation_ID
  ORDER BY
    count DESC
      ';

  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    if($row->count != '') {
      $tmp = array();
      $tmp['occupation'] = $row->occupation;
      $tmp['count'] = $row->count;

      array_push($results, $tmp);
    }
  }
  return $results;
}
```

**Graph View (for query causing 500):**

```
<div class="" id="occupationChart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $.getJSON("<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/ARDash/jsonReportsByOccupation", function(data){
  var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#occupationChart',
    data: {
      json: data,
      keys: {
        x: 'occupation',
        value: ['Number of incidents']
      },
      type: 'bar',
      empty: {
        label: {
          text: "No Data"
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      show: true,
      grouped: true
    },
    axis: {
      rotated: true,
      x: {
        label: {
          position: 'outer-center',
        },
        type: 'category',
        categories: 'occupation'
      },
      y: {
        tick: {
          format: d3.format("d"),
          outer: true,
          count: 4
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    }
  });
    });






</script>
```

Comment: What's in the error log?